# How can I get localstorage data in getStaticProps in next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, local-storage

I'm trying to get local storage data using this code but it's not working.

```
localStorageData = {
        id: localStorage.getItem("id"),
        token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
};
```

This code is inside getStaticProps().

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can not do such thing, due to the fact that `getStaticProps()` function gets called in server and we dont have access to `Web Api's` like `localStorage` in the server . they are accessible only in browser.